# postman collection sharing options for an enterprise?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, postman

I recently developed a new REST API for a company.  I've created a Postman collection including some sample requests for real-world scenarios. I need to share this collection with other members of the organization.

I found a "Publish Docs" menu option for Postman collections which is pretty cool.  It publishes web pages of the documentation and then displays the url for where the documentation can be accessed:

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1401123/RWML234Hd

One issue is that the documentation is publicly available to anyone who has the url.  Meaning that anyone on the internet could potentially access the documentation.  This is a corporate API and should only be accessible within the organization.

Another issue is that it appears that the published url changes every time I "Publish Docs."  That's a problem b/c I need to provide a static url for Postman examples on the corporate intranet page listing API resources. My manager won't spend any money on this. I like the documentation feature but:

1. The documentation should have a static url
2. The documentation should not be accessible by anyone on the internet who gets a hold of the url

Would I need to pay license costs to satisfy the 2 requirements listed above?  What would be my best free option?  The default free option for me would be to save off the collection json to a shared drive on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I've been asking this very question for a while now. Finally decided to implement a simple tool that generates an HTML document similar to what postman does. 
hope this helps -
https://github.com/karthiks3000/postman-doc-gen